# Alter a table which has non-unique non-clustered index to add a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, alter

I have a table named `Person` which already have few non-unique non-clustered index and one clustered index (based on primary key).

**I have to write two queries:**

- I need to alter the table to add column `birthplace`. Do I need to check any index while writing the `alter table person add birthplace varchar(128) not null`?
- My next requirement is I have another column named `cityCode narvar(10)`. This I need to include in my existing non-unique, non-clustered index. How should I write my script? should I drop my index and recreate it?

Please suggest. I am able to find some related questions, but not clear about `non-unique non-clustered` index.

Comment: For the first question, no, you don't have to do anything to existing indices.  If required, the add column operation might cause the indices to be recomputed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> alter table person add birthplace varchar(128) not null

Be aware when you specify `not null` without default value you will get error. It's recommended to add default value. But in case you can not consider any, then add column as nullable then update it later. At the end make it `NOT NULL` using below code:

```
alter table person Alter column birthplace varchar(128) not null
```

And if you want to involve new column to an existing index then use `CREATE INDEX` with `DROP_EXISTING` option. The performance is more efficient.  To do so,
generate a create index script then modify script by adding new column to the column list of index and then add this at the end of `CREATE INDEX` statement.

```
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)
```

Comment: In my experience, if the end goal is to have the column be non-nullable, it's easier to add the column as `NOT NULL` with a default constraint whose value is a nonce and back fill the data than to change `NULL` → `NOT NULL` after the back fill. Fun fact - you can drop the default constraint as soon as new rows have the new column provided explicitly.

Comment: @BenThul I agree with you about default constraint. But I would like to explain completely and consider all situation; then he could decide on his own.

Comment: Fair enough. In the same spirit, I thought it helpful to provide the information that would allow someone reading this to make that decision. That is, merely saying "you could do it this way or that way" without saying why one would choose one over the other at best leads to someone having to do the research to make that choice and at worst an inappropriate choice gets made and at the end it causes a lot more work.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks for your recommendation. I try to improve my answers like that.